# Access SessionStateProxy of child scope

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-7.2

After running `powershell.AddScript("code", true);` how do I get access to the session (`SessionStateProxy`) of the child scope that was created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SessionStateProxy` property belongs to the [*runspace*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) hosting the execution context:

```
// API will automatically create a default runspace when you don't explicitly pass one to PowerShell.Create()
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
  ps.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("targetPath", @"C:\some\path");
  // side-effect from `Set-Location` called from child scope is the same as when run in calling scope
  ps.AddScript(@"Set-Location -LiteralPath $targetPath", true);
  ps.AddStatement();
  // location change still persists in parent scope
  ps.AddScript(@"$PWD.Path");

  foreach(var outputItem in ps.Invoke())
    Console.WriteLine(outputItem.BaseObject);
}
```

The above will print `C:\some\path` (assuming that that directory exists).

Comment: If you add a second parameter of value true to AddScript. A child session is created, i need a way to access it and change is current working directory (changing the root one does not seem to affect it)

Comment: @Peter How exactly are you attempting to change the directory? The location stack doesn't care whether you modify it from a child scope, it'll still persist. `ps.AddScript(@"Set-Location C:\some\path", true).AddStatement().AddScript("$PWD.Path").Invoke()` correctly spits out `C:\some\path` for example

Comment: I updated the answer to more specifically show that calling `Set-Location` from a child-scope works perfectly fine

Comment: I had a bug in my code.. I will remove this question!

Comment: @Peter Good to hear you solved your problem. I don't see any reason to remove your post, there's nothing wrong with the question ("how do I access SessionStateProxy from a lone instance of the PowerShell class?") nor any buggy code present :)